# textview overlap on recycleview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I am using a recycleview to show the content and if the content have more than 7 rows the textviews underneath of the recycleview is getting overlapped.
     Please let me know how to fix this.Here is my code below.

This doesnt show the problem with lesser recycleview items say 3 or 4 but if I have more itesm like 7 to 8 then the issue is getting reproduced.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WelcomePageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_bg_gray">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contentDetailsSummary_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timeTakenToTransfer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/contentDetailsSummary_list">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assisted_acnt_tv"    --> this textview is overlapping on the recycleview items
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/assisted_acnt_setup"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/account_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/line_account_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/elevation_padding"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:background="@drawable/action_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/line_backup_ins"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/google_account_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/elevation_padding"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:background="@drawable/action_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/google_acnt_ids_btn"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_textsize" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTakenToTransfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        style="@style/textStyle_body"
        android:layout_above="@+id/uniqueTransactionId"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/uniqueTransactionId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        style="@style/textStyle_body"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_layout">

        <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/app_install_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            style="@style/textStyle_button"
            android:text="@string/install_apps"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_finish_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            style="@style/textStyle_button"
            android:text="@string/ept_finish_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: try using linear layout instead of relative layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WelcomePageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_bg_gray">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contentDetailsSummary_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timeTakenToTransfer">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assisted_acnt_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/assisted_acnt_setup"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/account_button_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/line_account_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/elevation_padding"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
                android:background="@drawable/action_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/line_backup_ins"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_textsize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/google_account_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/elevation_padding"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
                android:background="@drawable/action_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/google_acnt_ids_btn"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_textsize" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTakenToTransfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        style="@style/textStyle_body"
        android:layout_above="@+id/uniqueTransactionId"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/uniqueTransactionId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        style="@style/textStyle_body"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_layout">

        <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/app_install_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            style="@style/textStyle_button"
            android:text="@string/install_apps"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.abc.xyz.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_finish_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            style="@style/textStyle_button"
            android:text="@string/ept_finish_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome,Thanks a lot for the help